# How to create fields with groups using JForm?

Tags: joomla

I am making custom component and trying to make a form which would use JForm. I tried to set the group for fields in form manifest file, but that did not work out. Where are you supposed to set the group for the field? In manifest file, while preparing JForm object in the model or just before rendering the field? In the end I am trying to achieve that field names would look something like index[country][region][street], so that would require several groups within groups. Is that even possible?

At first I was fine by generating field name myself and reading data from JInput when form was submitted, but I got into problems when I wanted to bind existing data to the form before it is loaded. If I stick with manually generated field names for the form, then I need to manually generate keys far data entries as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can control field group by adding `<fields>` tag to the form manifest file.

```
 <fields name="groupName">
     <field type="text" name="field1"></field>
 </fields>
```

Produced output:

```
 <input name="groupName[field1]" type="text" />
```

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/getting-started-with-jform/